# overloaded functions produce ambiguous error

Tags: c++, standards, overloading

i have some overloaded function but in my test code some error are generated.

```c
inline void tt(uint8_t& v) { }
inline void tt(int8_t& v) { }
inline void tt(char& v) { }
inline void tt(uint16_t& v) { }
inline void tt(int16_t& v) { }
inline void tt(uint32_t& v) { }
inline void tt(int32_t& v) { }
inline void tt(uint64_t& v) { }
inline void tt(int64_t& v) { }

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    unsigned char t1;
    signed char t2;
    unsigned short t3;
    short t4;
    unsigned int t5;
    int t6;
    unsigned long t7;
    long t8;
    char t9;

    tt(t1);  // ok
    tt(t2);  // ok
    tt(t3);  // ok
    tt(t4);  // ok
    tt(t5);  // ok
    tt(t6);  // ok
    tt(t7);  // error
    tt(t8);  // error
    tt(t9);  // ok
}
```

**why is all working except (unsigned) long?** looking on [standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) long is at least (like all the other types) 32bit.

`There are five standard signed integer types: “signed char”, “short int”, “int”, “long int”, and “long long int”. In this list, each type provides at least as much storage as those preceding it in the list.`

i can avoid this by inserting

```
inline void tt(unsigned long int& v) { }
inline void tt(long int& v) { }
```

to the code. i would just like to know why this cast isn't work.

Comment: 1) That is definitely not the standard. [Try this](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf). 2) You didn't read the note below the table. It's officially at least 32 bits.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious i tried that but it also don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, on your compiler, none of the types for which you've overloaded `tt` are the same as `long`. On other compilers, one or more of them might be. Most likely, `int32_t` is an alias for `int` and `int64_t` is an alias for `long long`.

Even if, for example, `int` and `long` are the same *size*, they are not the same *type*, and so a reference to one cannot be converted to a reference to the other. In fact, you've quoted the part of the standard that says they are different types.

Comment: this shows that long long is int64_t, at least on gcc: http://ideone.com/clone/GmP0I0

Comment: @ArneMertz: On the particular platform that site runs ([32-bit Linux](http://ideone.com/2bH16Z)). On my computer (64-bit Linux), it's `long`.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ Standard (Draft N3225) says:

> There are five standard signed integer types : “signed char”, “short int”, “int”, “long int”, and “long long int”. In this list, each type provides at least as much storage as those preceding it in the list.

On MSVC12 I get `typedef unsigned int       uint32_t;` in the stdint.h.

Eventhough unsigned long is also 32bits it is still a different type.

Therefore none of your functions is overloaded to take (unsigned) long reference as an argument.

-edit-
If you change your functions to take their Parameters by value you will end up having an error due to an ambiguous call to tt().